# Javascript - generating expressions without operator overloading

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using three.js in a js project and I'm trying to calculate if a vector is still in an area like this

```
var THRESHOLD = 10;
if(!is_in_rect(camera.position - forward * THRESHOLD)))
   // do something
```

where camera.position and foward are [THREE.Vector3](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3) objects.

The problem with the approach above, although very readable, is that it's not working since js doesn't support operator overloading. I have to write something like

```
if(!in_rect(camera.position.clone().add(forward.clone().multiplyScalar(THRESHOLD)))
```

which looks kinda ugly to me.

Is there any other idiomatic way of doing this in js that I'm missing?

Comment: what you could do is to pass a string to your function `is_in_rect()`, and decompose the string to your 'ugly looking' syntax. A bit like you can pass strings to php's date. a bit of work for readability only, but if it gets complex, maybe that's worth it

Comment: Something like https://www.sweetjs.org/ might help you out

Comment: Couldnt one use *valueOf* for this?

Answer (score 1):

From the page you linked to:

> .addScaledVector ( v, s )
>
> Adds the multiple of v and s to this vector

so a bit better is:

```
camera.position.clone().addScaledVector(forward,THRESHOLD)
```

Also, there's no real reason to clone forward, as that won't be changed.

If I'm following what @T.J. is saying, and you want something more general, than my answer would be no, if `idomatic` means using `+` and `-`, if we're strictly sticking to JS. You could build your own framework to make things idomatic, such as a general addition operator:

```
var add = function(x,y):
    try {
         var sum = x + y;
         if ( s != undefined ) { return sum; }
         #otherwise
         sum = x.clone().add(y);
    } catch {
        #Otherwise threw something
        sum = x.add(y) #maybe another exception? nest try/catch.
    }
}
```

But this is a lot of work, as you would have to type check a lot since JS can add up stuff with impunity. Just trying to return `x+y` will often be undefined.  In my example perhaps testing for add functions before simple additions may be better.

This way you can create the `idiom` you like, if you think it's worth it, and use your `add` for everything (instead of `+` in my example). Probably grow it as you code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is: Is there a better way to do these sorts of expressions (generally). It could be a useful *comment*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I disagree, though now it's getting opinion based.  `addScaledVector` is more idomatic for adding a scaled vector, and removing redundant clone calls is also.

Comment: Yes, but again, that's not the question. It's an example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess I'm missing your point. I took his last example (said 'expression'), and made it more 'idomatic'. Is that not specifically what's written in the last line? Maybe you mean it should be 'more idomatic'?

Comment: The question isn't "how do I make this specific code better." It's "how do I write expressions like this **in general** in a better way, since JavaScript doesn't have operator overloading. It could be any expression. Saying how to write that one specific expression differently doesn't answer the question. It just offers an alternative for **one example**. Look again at the first part of the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I still feel he asked something more specific, but I edited to try and address your thoughts. Is that more what you mean?

Comment: Perhaps very marginally.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other idiomatic way of doing this in js that I'm missing?

Not really, no; you'd basically have to write yourself an expression parser, or use one that's already been written.

A couple of notes on that:

1. Doing that might be a bit easier with ES2015+'s [template literals and tagged template functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), since it would do some of the parsing for you. For instance, you might be able to give yourself tag function that would let you write:

   ```
   if(!is_in_rect(threval`${camera.position} - ${forward} * ${THRESHOLD}`)))
   ```

   `threval` would receive an array of the raw strings in that template, followed by the values of `camera.position`, `forward`, and `THRESHOLD`. So you could use that information to build up the sequence. But it would be non-trivial.
2. You could write yourself a Babel plugin to make your expressions first-class productions, and transpile. The advantage to that is that Babel provides a robust parsing infrastructure and tooling support.